# Uninitialized string offset

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
$alphabet = "1234567890";
$num = 30;
$size = strlen($alphabet); 
$key = null;
while ($num--) {$key .= $alphabet[rand(0, $size)];}
```

В последней строчке ошибка: **Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 10 in** Хотелось бы узнать чем она вызвана.

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда - ответ в тексте ошибки. Напишите $key = "".

Comment: Оказалось надо было просто написать $size = strlen($alphabet) - 1;

Comment: @yetirider, нумерация элементов массива начинается с 0, а не 1. Поэтому когда rand(0,10)==10 выскакивает ошибка.